# Transpose ColumnName and Value KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a dataset that contains many columns with dates.  I would like return only the column names and dates then sort by date.  In excel, I would accomplish this by transposing the data then sorting.  How can I accomplish the same in KQL?

```
let T1 = datatable (Date1:string, Date2:string, Date3:string, Date4:string, Date5:string, Date6:string, Date7:string, Date8:string, Date9:string, Date10:string, )[
"2021-11-3", "2021-11-4",
"2021-11-5", "2021-11-6",
"2021-11-7", "2021-11-8",
"2021-11-9", "2021-11-10",
"2021-11-11", "2021-11-12"];
T1
```

**Result:**

```
Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4.........   
2021-11-3   2021-11-4   2021-11-5   2021-11-6.....
```

**Desired Result:**

```
DateType  Date
Date1     2021-11-3
Date2     2021-11-4
Date3     2021-11-5
Date4     2021-11-6
...       ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `narrow()` plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/narrowplugin

```
datatable (Date1:string, Date2:string, Date3:string, Date4:string, Date5:string, Date6:string, Date7:string, Date8:string, Date9:string, Date10:string)
[
    "2021-11-3", "2021-11-4", "2021-11-5", "2021-11-6", "2021-11-7", "2021-11-8", "2021-11-9", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12"
]
| evaluate narrow()
| project DateType = Column, Date = Value
```

| DateType | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Date1 | 2021-11-3 |
| Date10 | 2021-11-12 |
| Date2 | 2021-11-4 |
| Date3 | 2021-11-5 |
| Date4 | 2021-11-6 |
| Date5 | 2021-11-7 |
| Date6 | 2021-11-8 |
| Date7 | 2021-11-9 |
| Date8 | 2021-11-10 |
| Date9 | 2021-11-11 |